# Why does is_sorted not work correctly with greater_equal?

Tags: c++, stl

I have C++ code:

```
auto test = vector<unsigned int>({3, 2, 1});
assert(is_sorted(test.begin(), test.end(), greater_equal<unsigned int>())); //passes

test = vector<unsigned int>({3, 1, 1});
assert(is_sorted(test.begin(), test.end(), greater_equal<unsigned int>())); //fails
```

Why does second one fail?

Comment: Note that `std::greater<unsigned int>()` would succeed. That's probably what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_sorted` has requirements for the comparison function object. In particular, it must satisfy the requirements of Compare concept. The same requirement is for most (all?) comparison objects used by the standard library .

`std::greater_equal` does not satisfy the requirements of Compare concept. In particular, it does not satisfy the *irreflexivity*: `For all a, comp(a,a)==false` nor *asymmetry*: `If comp(a,b)==true then comp(b,a)==false` (for all a,b) properties. In other words, `std::greater_equal` is not a strict weak ordering.

As pointed out by aschepler, `std::greater` satisfies the Compare concept, so that's probably what you are looking for.

Comment: cppreference.com describes irreflexivity as `equiv(a, b), an expression equivalent to !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`

Comment: @Barmar that's odd. That seems like the definition of `equiv` relation, rather than description of a property of a relation. I don't see mention of (ir)reflexivity on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare). I checked the names of the properties from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) and copied the matching definition from cppreference.

Comment: They imply the same thing when you combine asymmetry and irreflexivity.

Comment: @Barmar I don't think that the definition of `equiv` itself implies anything. Its the properties given to `equiv` that do so. `equiv` of `std::greater_equal` does not satisfy all (or even any?) of those properties. But yes, those requirements appear to (at least partially) define the same properties as the direct requirements of `comp`.

Comment: That's all I was saying -- this is the way cppreference describes the requirements, by relating the constraints on `Compare` to object equivalence.

Answer (score 0):

`greater_equal` can be used with `is_sorted` specifically to forbid multiple identical elements, thus enforcing a strict ordering (same, but ascending, for `less_equal`).

Note that the predicate is used in negation:

> A sequence is sorted with respect to a comparator comp if for any iterator it pointing to the sequence and any non-negative integer n such that it + n is a valid iterator pointing to an element of the sequence, comp(*(it + n), *it) evaluates to false. ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted_until))